# CKEditor no muestra datos al editar por segunda vez

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

necesito ayuda con lo siguiente:
Sucede que tengo un sistema corriendo con AngularJS 1.3.13 e incorporé un editor de texto, en este caso CKEditor 4.14.

1.- Mientras creo el texto, y agrego la información de contenido me funciona todo bien:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Ya guardada mi "Campaña", al momento de presionar en el botón de editar de dicha campaña me carga todo el contenido (la primera vez), pero al momento de querer editar por segunda vez la misma campaña u alguna otra, el contenido correspondiente al CKEditor no se muestra, queda en blanco. La única forma que me vuelva a mostrar bien todo el contenido a editar es refrescando la página.

3.- Revise y verifique que la información fuese traída desde la base de datos de forma correcta.

4.- Así está mi directiva de CKEditor, la cual se encuentra en un archivo llamado ckEditor.js

```
//Sidebar Menu Handle
'use strict';

angular.module('GestionCP')
.directive('ckEditor', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
            var ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0], {
                extraPlugins: 'uploadimage',
                extraPlugins:   'imagebrowser',
                filebrowserUploadUrl: 'librerias/ckeditor/upload.php?type=Images',
                imageBrowser_listUrl: "images.json",
                defaultLanguage: 'es-mx',
                height: 400
            });

            if (!ngModel) return;

      ck.on('instanceReady', function() {
        ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      });

      function updateModel() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
          });
      }

      ck.on('change', updateModel);
      ck.on('key', updateModel);
      ck.on('dataReady', updateModel);
            ck.on('paste', updateModel);
      ck.on('selectionChange', updateModel);

      ngModel.$render = function(value) {
        return ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
      };
        }
    };
});
```

5.- Así se encuentra el textarea a utilizar con el CKEditor:

```
<textarea ck-editor ng-model="config.campos.nom.campanha_Contenido" ng-required="config.campos.prop.campanha_Contenido.required"></textarea>
```

6.- Así solicito/recibo la información desde la base de datos en el controller de la campaña:

```
CampanhaService.Listar(vm.id, function(response){
                        if(response.success){
                            vm.config.campos.nom = response.datos;

                            var horainicio = response.datos.campanha_HoraInicio.split(':');
                            var horainicio2 = new Date();
                            horainicio2.setHours(horainicio[0]);
                            horainicio2.setMinutes(horainicio[1]);
                            vm.HoraInicio = horainicio2;
                        }
                    });
```

7.- Por último, así se encuentra mi config.json:

```
"campos": {
        "nom": {
            "campanha_Id": "",
            "campanha_Nombre": "",
            "campanha_FechaInicio": "",
            "campanha_HoraInicio": "",
            "campanha_FechaTermino": "",
            "campanha_HoraTermino": "",
            "campanha_Estado": "",
            "campanha_Contenido": ""
        },
```

¿Alguna idea de donde puede encontrarse el error?